# how do I find a new page I just created so that I can link it on another page?

Tags: links

I just created a new Basic page, and I want to link to it on another page, but I can't find it when I browse for it in the Create Link option.  I'm VERY new to this platform.

Comment: I'm also a very basic user of web platforms of any sort. I am editing the keysunitedway.org site with OneEach.

Comment: Welcome!  This appears to be a non-CiviCRM question - "Basic Page" is Drupal terminology.  Drupal sites vary, but most will have a toolbar along the top with a "Content" option to find your recently created content.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I just went into my browser history and found it that way, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about Drupal and not CiviCRM?